# solving equations and using values obtained in other calculations - SAGE

Tags: sage

the function solve() in SAGE returns symbolic values for the variables i solve the equations for. for e.g:

```
sage: s=solve(eqn,y)
sage: s
[y == -1/2*(sqrt(-596*x^8 - 168*x^7 - 67*x^6 + 240*x^5 + 144*x^4 - 60*x - 4) + 8*x^4 + 11*x^3 + 12*x^2)/(15*x + 1), y == 1/2*(sqrt(-596*x^8 - 168*x^7 - 67*x^6 + 240*x^5 + 144*x^4 - 60*x - 4) - 8*x^4 - 11*x^3 - 12*x^2)/(15*x + 1)]
```

My problem is that i need to use the values obtained for y in other calculations, but I cannot assign these values to any other variable. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 10):

(1) You should visit [ask.sagemath.org](http://ask.sagemath.org), the Stack Overflow-like forum for Sage users, experts, and developers!  `</plug>`

(2) If you want to use the values of a solve() call in something, then it's probably easiest to use the solution_dict flag:

```
sage: x,y = var("x, y")
sage: eqn = x**4+5*x*y+3*x-y==17
sage: solve(eqn,y)
[y == -(x^4 + 3*x - 17)/(5*x - 1)]
sage: solve(eqn,y,solution_dict=True)
[{y: -(x^4 + 3*x - 17)/(5*x - 1)}]
```

This option gives the solutions as a list of dictionaries instead of a list of equations.  We can access the results like we would any other dictionary:

```
sage: sols = solve(eqn,y,solution_dict=True)
sage: sols[0][y]
-(x^4 + 3*x - 17)/(5*x - 1)
```

and then we can assign that to something else if we like:

```
sage: z = sols[0][y]
sage: z
-(x^4 + 3*x - 17)/(5*x - 1)
```

and substitute:

```
sage: eqn2 = y*(5*x-1)
sage: eqn2.subs(y=z)
-x^4 - 3*x + 17
```

et cetera.  While IMHO the above is more convenient, you could also access the same results without solution_dict via .rhs():

```
sage: solve(eqn,y)[0].rhs()
-(x^4 + 3*x - 17)/(5*x - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have unknown number of variables you can use **kwargs to pass data calculated with solve to next expressions. Here's example:

B_set is an list of variables and its filled in runtime so i dont know
names of variables and their quantity at the time of writing the code

```
solution = solve(system_of_equations, B_set)[0]
pretty_print(solution)
```

For example this gives me:
[result of solving system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFvEX.png)

I cant use this answer for further calculations so lets convert it to usable form

```
solution = {str(elem.lhs()): elem.rhs() for elem in solution}
```

Which gives us:
[result converted to dictionary with string keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaFRk.png)

Then we just pass this as **kwargs

```
approximation = approximation_function(**solution)
pretty_print(approximation)
```

And that converts this:
[approximation without values from solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE1NY.png)

Into this:
[approximation with values from solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzb5o.png)

Note: if you use dictionary output from solve() you still need to convert keys to string.